# Ending a Pipe Operation

Tags: powershell, pipeline

Is there any way of ending a pipe operation while you are in a filter?

A good use would be to get the first n elements of the list, similar to SQL's TOP statement.  If we wrote a filter, call it "Top", we could retrieve the first 3 elements like so:

```
dir | Top 3
```

Once we have returned the first three, we don't need to process any more elements and in effect we want to be able to tell the pipe

> Please don't give me any more elements

**I know that Select-Object has the -First argument but that is not the question I am asking.**

I have answered the question [Powershell equivalent to F# Seq.forall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092159/powershell-equivalent-to-f-seq-forall/13142823#13142823) but instead I would rather implement it as a filter which ends pipeline input.  If there was an operation called "end-pipeline", I would implement ForAll as:

```
filter ForAll([scriptblock] $predicate) {
    process {
        if ( @($_ | Where-Object $predicate).Length -eq 0 ) {
            $false;
            end-pipeline;
        }
    }
    end {
        $true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use "break" statement, it will behave as your "end-pipeline" cmdlet

Comment: It works.  However the link http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tobias/archive/2010/01/01/cancelling-a-pipeline.aspx provided by Christian makes a big deal about ending a pipeline.  Is the "break" statement safe to use in all situations?

Comment: generally speaking, it's safe, but it could break the execution of the whole script if you invoke a script file which contains break that is not within some loops like while, for etc.

Comment: @TahirHassan - `break` will stop the rest of the script from executing. Try: `0..9 | .{process{if($_ -lt 5){$_} else{break;}}}| measure; write 'end'`. Note that in that example, `measure` does not return anything and "end" does not get printed. You could wrap the whole pipeline in a `try..catch`, but the measure command at the end of the pipeline still would not work. I have been trying to find a good solution to this problem, but haven't yet; see my question at http://stackoverflow.com/q/8749206/291709

Comment: Aware! If you use `break` in a pipeline, which in turn is in some loop, then the pipe will stop, but the loop also!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can add a `return` if the condition is reached.

Look [here](http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tobias/archive/2010/01/01/cancelling-a-pipeline.aspx) for some example

This maybe works:

```
filter ForAll([scriptblock] $predicate)
{
  process
         {        
            if ( @($input | Where-Object $predicate).length -eq 0 ) 
              {        
                 $false
                 return;
              }
         }
  end    
         {
            $true
         }
}
```

this works:

```
filter aaa {    
process 
{      
  if ( ++$i -gt 5 )
  {
      return
  }
  else
  {
      $_
  }
}
}

dir | aaa # return first five element of the pipe...
```

Comment: Thanks for the link - I will check it out.

Comment: I tried return - it returns out of the process block rather than out of the filter.

Comment: This still executes the process block for each element... I wanted the processing to stop.  Using "break;" as Jackie suggested does this.